# React: Re-render parent component based on Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one parent component, named `Cart` and another component named `Items`.
Basically, I am getting an array of objects from Node.js and save it as a state in `Cart` component.

My Cart Component:

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            cartData:null,
        }

    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        _isMounted = false

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        _isMounted = true
        this.callApi()
        .then(res => {if(_isMounted) this.setState({cartData: res.express})})
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }

    callApi = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/myCart');
        const body = await response.json();
        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

        return body;

    };

    mapOutItems(){
        return this.state.cartData.map((item,index) => (
            <Item
                key={index}
                desc={item.desc}
                amount={item.amount}
                total={item.total}
                delete={this.handleDelete(item.desc)}
            />
        ))
    }
    handleDelete(desc){
        axios({method: "post", url: "/remove", data:{name: desc}})

        axios("/myCart").then(function (response){
            this.setState({cartData : response.data.express})
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.mapOutItems()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cart;
```

Item Component

```
class Item extends React.Component{
    handleClick(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        axios({method: "post", url: "/remove", data:{name: this.props.desc}})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        {this.props.desc}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        {this.props.amount}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        {this.props.total}
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick=onClick={this.props.delete}>
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item;
```

Logic: My `Cart` component will get data from the endpoint at Node.js. It is an array of objects and `Cart` component use it to populate the `item` component. The `item` component has a delete button that once trigger will send the name of the item it wants to delete and use MongoDB's query to delete the items. 
However, the backend showed that it is successfully deleted it, but the parent `Cart` component still render's the items that have been deleted. I wanted to find a way to trigger a re-render a Cart once the item is deleted.

Edit:

The simple data from the url is an array of object like that looks like this:

```
[{ desc: 'Market', total: 4000, amount: 1 }
{ desc: 'Data', total: 17000, amount: 1 }]
```

Response in the handleDelete() is the response of axios called, with format like the following:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: {express: Array(1)}
headers: {date: "Wed, 03 Oct 2018 18:30:02 GMT", etag: "W/"37-QxQ/lxfNH/fWEmtfXYAG1YLiA/E"", x-powered-by: "Express", content-length: "55", vary: "Accept-Encoding", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

From `response.data`, i get `express: Array(1)` so from the `response.data.express`, I am actually getting the array of data

After @Code-Apprentice's edit. Now the problem is that, the second axios called did not invoke get invoke after the first remove call is done. i tried to print out what I got back from that that second axios and it is the same data as the what are first rendered.

Comment: I'd recommend moving the logic out of your `Item` and into the parent component - you can use a callback prop to let the parent component know when delete has been clicked. Then the parent component can update its own state (which will trigger a re-render).

Comment: @JoeClay I am new to React, how would I move the delete logic to the parent component

Comment: Please show an example of `this.state.cartData` that comes from the initial request in `componentDidMount`. Then what is `response` in the `.then()` handler in `handleDelete()`. You probably need a `.then` after the call to the `/remove` route before you make a request to `/myCart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a rerender of any component, you can call `this.setState()`. In this case, you need to remove the deleted item from `cartData` and call something like `this.setState({cartData: updatedData});`. (Be sure you map over `cartData` instead of `testData` in `render()`.)

In order to do this, you need a callback function that is passed as a prop from `Cart` to `Item`. Call it `onDelete()`, for example. This function is responsible to implement the logic described in the previous paragraph. You can implement this in one of two ways:

1. Fetch the data from the back end. This will give you exactly the list of items that are in your database.
2. Remove the deleted item from `this.state.cardData`. This is quicker because you don't have to make a network request, but it risks deleting the wrong item so that the component's state is not the same as the data in the backend database.

**Addendum:**

In your current version, you attempt to pass a callback with this line of code:

```
delete={this.handleDelete(item.desc)}
```

The problem is that this calls `this.handleDelete()` **immediately** as you map over each item in your cart data. So every item is deleted. Instead, you need to create a function which will do this when the button is clicked:

```
delete={() => this.handleDelete(item.desc)}
```

Comment: I have tried this way. However, whenever I tried to delete one, all of them get deleted it. Also, there is no setstate trigger even though I set the state from the newly fetched data. Please see my edit.

Comment: Actually, i don't know why, the delete action is invoked as long as the page is rendered. And all of the items are deleted

Comment: @SpencerOvetsky See my edit to show you how to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the another approach by manipulating the data in client instead of server and then send to server and it seems to worked. Thanks!

Comment: @SpencerOvetsky that sounds great! For both approaches, the same concepts apply, the `delete` prop must be set to a function, not the return value form a function call (unless the function call returns a function, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function in the parent component that take an item id and this function will be responsible for making the delete request and after the response return remove the deleted item from the array and setState for the parent.
Send this function to each item on parent render method.
In the child component when the user click the delete button will invoke the passed function from the parent and pass the function the id.

Answer (score 0):

So basically once you delete an item you need update your state in your cart component. To do that you can again fetch the data or delete just that item from cart state. In the following snippet, handleDelete will splice the item from cartData and set it to state which will trigger component render.

```
<Item
    key={index}
    desc={item.desc}
    amount={item.amount}
    total={item.total}
    onDelete={this.handleDelete}
/>

handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    axios({method: "post", url: "/remove", data:{name: this.props.desc}}).then(() => {this.props.handleDelete(this.props.desc)})
}
```

Comment: so handleDelete just fetch the state again?